# Opening a device node in a device driver in linux

Tags: linux

I am writing a device driver on Xillinux that will read and write data to an FPGA application over Xillybus.

Basically I want to create device nodes such as `/dev/pe1`, and when I write to the nodes my device driver will form packets of data and then write the packets into the xillybus nodes eg. `/dev/xillybus_write_32`

Is it possible to simply open an existing `/dev` node inside a kernel module, and then perform I/O operations on it? Or is it better to just write a userspace driver?

Comment: Start reading: **[LDD3](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)**.  The meat of what you want is covered in chapters 3 & 6.

Answer (score 0):

After reading LDD3 and some other articles on kernel development, I've decided to abandon the idea of writing my custom device driver and put the logic in runtime instead. Thanks for the advice *goldilocks*.